Sifted colimits commutes with finite limits in the stable infinity category Mod(A)
For a simplicial ring $A$, consider the stable infinity category Mod(A), then:
Do sifted colimits (indexed by a sifted simplicial set K) commute with finite limits in this infinity stable category?
I believe this is true, by Lemma 5.5.8.12 in HTT, this can be reduced to the proposition 'formation of products in Mod(A) preserves K-indexed colimits separately in each variable'.
I want to use this conclusion to reduce the proof of some exact sequence $F(A)\rightarrow G(A)\rightarrow K(A)$ to the case when $A$ is the finite free module over $A$, which situation can be much easier.
Any reference for this is very welcome.

Yes according to https://mathoverflow.net/questions/245137.

Stability is a powerful concept in higher category theory and that's the key here. We can omit the word sifted: All colimits commute with finite limits in stable $\infty$-categories!
Indeed, colimits commute with finite colimits but because we are working in a stable setting, this implies that colimits also commute with finite limits [Higher Algebra, Proposition 1.1.4.1]. (In the process we are tacitly using that functor categories to stable $\infty$-categories are stable again [Higher Algebra, Proposition 1.1.3.1].)
This interplaying behaviour between finite limits and colimits is the essence of stability and extremely useful in practice - your question is one of many examples.
